# Removing /EHsc from single target

Tags: c++, cmake

I have CMake project with multi targets. One of them is CLR wrapper for native C++ code. I want to disable the `/EHsc` flag for only this target. I tried:

```
get_target_property(MYPROPS ${DOT_NET_WRAPPER_NAME} COMPILE_FLAGS)
message(${MYPROPS})
STRING( REPLACE "/EHsc" "" MYPROPS ${MYPROPS})
set_target_properties(${DOT_NET_WRAPPER_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${MYPROPS})
```

It prints : `MYPROPS-NOTFOUND`

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `COMPILE_FLAGS` is deprecated, its written in the property documentation. Use `COMPILE_OPTIONS` instead.

Secondly, the problem might occur due to not quoting strings. I cannot reproduce when quoting:

```
project(demo LANGUAGES C)

file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/a.c"
    [[
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) { printf("a\n"); return 0; }
    ]])

add_executable(A "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/a.c")

target_compile_options(A PRIVATE "/EHsc")

get_property(options TARGET A PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS)
message("Initial COMPILE_OPTIONS: ${options}")

string(REPLACE "/EHsc" "" new_options "${options}")

set_property(TARGET A PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "${new_options}")

get_property(options TARGET A PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS)
message("New COMPILE_OPTIONS: ${options}")
```

The above produces

```
Initial COMPILE_OPTIONS: /EHsc
New COMPILE_OPTIONS:
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: <...>
```